# Need some help on document template creation in word

Tags: microsoft-word, templates, documents

I need some help/suggestion or pointing to some resources about creating a template in word. The template I am trying to create is to share with third parties. The idea is the fist page has a header that is not repeated, the third page is the only page that has a header that repeat in odd pages. the second, fourth and all even pages doesn't have a header.

This is the link to the sample of the document in pdf https://1drv.ms/f/s!AkH1W48iWElCkrZc07atDg4n5Fseog

Comment: See http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/FrontMatterRibbon.htm and http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/sections2007.htm#PageNumbers and http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/sections2007.htm#Recap_of_Header/Footer_settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When setting the header and footer, you may only need to go to the **Header & Footer** tab and check the **Different First Page** and **Different Odd & Even Pages** in the **Options** group.
[image]

Any misunderstandings, pelase let me know.

Comment: hi VIki. 
Thanks for your feedback. I got the header work as i want. 
what is the best way for the borders of the document  to change dynamically when the user go to the next page? Currently I use frame and the page borders. But when the user go to the next page, the frame must change from the left to right. What is the best way to do this.

Comment: Hi @joelcongo, the border issue has nothing to do with the topic of this thread, please post a new question about the new issue. Besides, please mark the useful reply as an answer. Thanks for your understanding!

Comment: Hi Viki. Sorry for that. I  understand.  I will create a new topic about my new issue.